# Running the same function with different parameters at different sessions of R at the same time

Tags: r, session, multiple-instances

I have written a function in R to compute the MSEs of different estimators by using Monte Carlo simulation. Let's call it here as MSE(n,B), where n is the sample size and B is the number of repetitions in simulation. I want to run the MSE function for n=10,20,50,100 and B=10^5. 
My question is that, Can I open 4 different sessions of R and run the MSE function for each value of n at a different session of R at the same time?

Doesn't it invalidate the results?

Comment: Yes this will work. Each session will return a different MSE based on the values of `n` and `B` you provide.

Comment: if you are doing it for speed though, just use parallelization like foreach. Much cleaner in the long run and easier to keep track of what have you done